# On tests of topological superconductivity

Tags: superconductivity, topological-order

What experimental procedures determine if a superconducting crystal (say 2D i.e. layered material) is a topological superconductor/not?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70854/experimental-signature-of-topological-superconductor